Survey with forced ranking
I have created a survey with a ranking scale of 1 = Least effective, 2= Somewhat effective 3= Effective 4 = Most effective.
People answering the questions were forced to select only one response per column. 
The question was for example: Please rate the effectiveness of the following financial instruments in promoting the use of homegrown natural fibre insulation products, using a scale of 1 to 4. (Answer FI1/FI2/FI3/FI4)
How do I calculate the reliability of the survey since I cannot calculate the Cronbach's Alpha because the variance of the sum of each responce is zero.

Welcome to Cross Validated! This strikes me as possibly a variant of either Guttman or Thurstone scaling. Have you ever looked into those methods?

Cronbach's alpha doesn't seem appropriate here, regardless of the method of ranking. Alpha is (at least somewhat) appropriate for scales that consist of adding the scores on items. That doesn't seem sensible here.
You could give the same set of questions to the same people and then you could assess test-retest reliability.
